# There's GROUP BY issue with Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I can't do this sql with group by somehow.

```
SELECT aid, auid FROM 
  [my_dataset.table_name]
GROUP BY aid
LIMIT 1000
```

The error said.

```
Error: (L2:9): Expression 'auid' is not present in the GROUP BY list
```

If I remove group by, then it's available.

```
SELECT aid, auid FROM 
  [my_dataset.table_name]
LIMIT 1000
```

I'm so glad anyone can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In one of the comments I read you want the first value in the scope of the function. And if you come from MySQL adding `FIRST` function to the query helps you:

```
SELECT aid, FIRST(auid) FROM 
  [my_dataset.table_name]
GROUP BY aid
LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#groupby
You should either

1. add this field to your group by
   or
2. use aggregation function with this field

Comment: Oops...It is completely different from RDBMS...
So, how do we extract the records with unique aid?

Comment: it is not clear what you ask in above comment. please submit new question and and I will be more than glad to try to answer it

Comment: Got it. Thank you sir!
I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select `auid` since it's not involved in any aggregate function. 
You are grouping your rows based on `aid`, how would it select which values of `auid` to return? If you want both `auid` and `aid` you need to group by both fields.

```
SELECT aid, auid 
FROM 
  [my_dataset.table_name]
GROUP BY aid, auid
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: > You are grouping your rows based on aid, how would it select which values of auid to return?
In mysql, I think they returns the value in the first record which is found.
I excepted the same behaviour. I completely misunderstood.

Comment: I'm not only grouping by aid